# Which is the most clever solution to initialize a binary a tree using Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

Let's imagine we have the following class:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, right=None, left=None):
        self.value, self.right, self.left = value, right, left

tree = Tree(75, Tree(95), Tree(64))
```

Now, let's suppose we have to initialize the following numbers **only using the class above**:

[image]

Which could be the most clever algorithm to solve the problem above? It's unnecessary doing it recursively (and maybe not possible, I don't know), but it would be appreciated.

**If the problem can't be solved** using the class above, please provide some other solution.

Comment: Homework during summer? I don't think so. And if you don't believe: http://projecteuler.net/problem=18

Comment: A binary tree may not be the best data structure for this dataset -- it doesn't have the shape of a binary tree. Furthermore, a unidirectional binary tree like the one you model here won't lead you to the best solution!

Comment: Well, let's say that the problem about the link above and the one about this question are separated.

Comment: Even so, I still wouldn't use a binary tree to represent this. It's tiny and its bounds are fixed. I'd just use a 2-d array.

Comment: If you really want to do a binary tree, then any native way would do. I tried to update my answer but I cannot see why you would have problem instantiate the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must noticed that the triangle is not a binary tree.

In fact, in treating it as a tree, you are enumerating all the possible paths, thus leading to a O(2^n) algorithm, since you are branching for each number.

Can it be solved this way? Of course, it has 15 levels, 2^(15 - 1) = 16384, you'll solve it well under PE's minute guideline. But it is not a good solution.

Hint: this is a dynamic programming question.

Comment: Then consider the that "If the problem can't be solved using the class above, please provide some other solution."

Comment: Hint: this is a dynamic programming question. If you are doing Project Euler, you should first try to come up with something; solving problem there can be great exercises. Also, this is a classic problem, just search for dynamic programming triangle.

Comment: Is there any other Stack Exchange site where I can ask about this?

Comment: If you just want to use the tree, the you just need to loop through it, or do a traversal. As for other SE sites, this is the right one - CS might fit but I doubt it will be better than here.

Comment: Remember that to solve this problem you only need to find the path with the maximal sum, not the path itself. Is there any way you can work out all possible sums? Sometimes starting at the end and working backwards is helpful.

Comment: Well, I'll try to solve it on my own, even if I said that solving using other data structures was permitted. Anyway, thanks for answers/comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the data structure you want:

```
tri_str='''\
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23'''

triangle=[map(int,line.split()) for line in tri_str.splitlines()]
```

Now `triangle` is a matrix of integers of that text.

You *can* add then all up to find the max path, but it is easier to go from the other way -- from the bottom.

If you do not want to solve this yourself, just [Google the answer](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=python+project+euler+problem+18&oq=python+project+euler+problem+18&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l2.2015.16166.0.17127.31.16.0.15.15.0.127.1338.13j3.16.0....0...1c.1.20.psy-ab.es1w_QZHfBA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49260673,bs.1,d.cGE&fp=96ef8c934cbd66df&biw=1242&bih=1220) I suppose

Comment: This problem wasn't related to the Project Euler one, otherwise I'd directly asked about it. Anyway, thanks for help.